# Float DIV is not fixed

Tags: javascript

I install Float Left Right Advertising plugin on my site: [www.displej.me](http://displej.me) and I set banners at the side of site. But when you scroll baners are not fixed, they follow page but they are refreshing and blinking. Also, when I'm scrolling down they stay fixed aside and later start to follow the page. Ths is JS code:

```
function FloatTopDiv() 
{ 
    startLX = ((document.body.clientWidth -MainContentW)/2) - (LeftBannerW+LeftAdjust) , startLY = TopAdjust; 
    startRX = ((document.body.clientWidth -MainContentW)/2) + (MainContentW+RightAdjust) , startRY = TopAdjust; 
    var d = document; 
    function ml(id) 
    { 
        var el=d.getElementById?d.getElementById(id):d.all?d.all[id]:d.layers[id]; 
        el.sP=function(x,y){this.style.left=x + 'px';this.style.top=y + 'px';}; 
        el.x = startRX; 
        el.y = startRY; 
        return el; 
    } 
    function m2(id) 
    { 
        var e2=d.getElementById?d.getElementById(id):d.all?d.all[id]:d.layers[id]; 
        e2.sP=function(x,y){this.style.left=x + 'px';this.style.top=y + 'px';}; 
        e2.x = startLX; 
        e2.y = startLY; 
        return e2; 
    } 
    window.stayTopLeft=function() 
    { 
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) 
            var pY =  document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
        else if (document.body) 
            var pY =  document.body.scrollTop; 
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 200){startLY = 3;startRY = 3;} else {startLY = TopAdjust;startRY = TopAdjust;}; 
        ftlObj.y += (pY+startRY-ftlObj.y)/1; 
        ftlObj.sP(ftlObj.x, ftlObj.y); 
        ftlObj2.y += (pY+startLY-ftlObj2.y)/1; 
        ftlObj2.sP(ftlObj2.x, ftlObj2.y); 
        setTimeout("stayTopLeft()", 1); 
    } 
    ftlObj = ml("divAdRight"); 
    //stayTopLeft(); 
    ftlObj2 = m2("divAdLeft"); 
    stayTopLeft(); 
} 
function ShowAdDiv() 
{ 
    var objAdDivRight = document.getElementById("divAdRight"); 
    var objAdDivLeft = document.getElementById("divAdLeft");        
    objAdDivRight.style.display = "block"; 
    objAdDivLeft.style.display = "block"; 
    FloatTopDiv(); 
}
```

What to do? I try to change the numbers in the code but not sucsses.

Answer (score 0):

> clear:both

is something I would try to keep the sides free from the centered divs movements.

Comment: clear: both should only be used if the element have a position of absolute. Yeah I was wrong, good luck with solving your problem.